# Copyable Coldfusion SQL Exception

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

Whenever CF throws an error I get an email with all the exception information. Every time it involves a database error I get the SQL, WHERE and QueryError information, which is nice.

```
SQL  SELECT FooID FROM FooTable WHERE FooID = (param 1)
WHERE    (param 1) = [type='IN', class='java.lang.Integer', value='47', sqltype='CF_SQL_INTEGER'] 
Error   [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Insufficient clearance to break temporal directive.
```

However if it's a particular long winded query with multiple cfqueryparams, it becomes cumbersome to search for and replace the params to run that same query through MSSQL. I've always wanted to be able to programmatically include a copyable query line so that I can quickly run it through a query window.

Comment: The ColdFusion Muse has [this blog post](http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2012/11/1/adding.values.back.to.debug.queries) about query params.

Comment: (Edit) I am guessing this is for a dev server (where debugging is enabled), so that is a good option. For a prod server, you would need a different approach.

Answer (score 2):

I've finally created this helper function to build that copyable query line:

```
<cffunction name="limnSQLDump" output="no" access="public" returntype="string">
        <cfargument name="sql" required="yes" type="string">
        <cfargument name="params" required="yes" type="string">
        <cfset var arrParam = ListToArray(arguments.params, ' , ', false, true)> <!--- Arrayify Dat Param String --->
        <cfset var sub = StructNew()>
        <cfset var objParam = StructNew()>

        <cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(arrParam)#" index="i"> <!--- Loop through each param string --->
            <cfset arrParam[i] = REReplace(arrParam[i], '\(param \d+\) = \[([^\]]+)\]', '\1', 'all')> <!--- Scoop out the meat --->
            <cfset sub = REFind("([^=, ]+)='([^']*)'", arrParam[i], 1, true)> <!--- Prep For Surgery --->
            <cfset objParam = StructNew()> <!--- Preheat oven --->

            <cfloop condition="#sub.pos[1]#"> <!--- Surgically get Key/Value --->
                <cfset objParam[Mid(arrParam[i], sub.pos[2], sub.len[2])] = Mid(arrParam[i], sub.pos[3], sub.len[3])>
                <cfset sub = REFind("([^=, ]+)='([^']*)'", arrParam[i],  sub.pos[1]+sub.len[1], true)>
            </cfloop>

            <!--- Serve (Feeds 3) --->
            <cfset sql = REReplace(sql, '\(param '&i&'\)', (objParam.class NEQ 'java.lang.Integer' ? "'"&objParam.value&"'" : objParam.value))>
        </cfloop>

        <cfreturn sql>
    </cffunction>
```

Any feedback would be appreciated as I went through a myriad of different routes myself before I settled with this (going from specific to abstract and back again). In the end, I decided to break out the entire param string into an array (which after all basically is an array), regex the exact parameters and replace the whole string with it, then loop through the parameters and make an object equivalent so that it can be clearly referenced with the REReplace when making the substitutions to the SQL string.

I personally would've loved to have simply been able to do something akin to `<cfset arrParam[i] = Evaluate("{"&arrParam[i])&"}">` considering that, save for the brackets, the param contents are basically an inline object.

Comment: Without reading your code, I suggest that it doubles the quotes for parameters like O'Reilly, but not for parameters like {d '2013-02-28'}.  On the other hand, considering what the OP intends to use the function for, perfection might not be necessary.

Comment: Ah, good catch. The regex to extract the contents doesn't get everything if there's a single quote inside. I'll need to adjust the regex to handle that so that I can add a Replace to convert single quotes to double single quotes (one could even called the double quotes). Might just do another ListToArray instead.

Comment: FYI: String values containing the multi-delimiter ie `(space),(space)` will also cause problems.

Comment: If you want code reviewing, you should post it on Code Review. You've not `VAR`ed `i`, btw. And the comments are pointless. Comments should not explain what the code is doing (the code does that), they should explain - if necessary - WHY the code is doing it.

Comment: @Leigh Yeah, as soon as I started exploring the `O'Reily` example I found quite a few cases that made the function implode, not least of which was that one (which made me call it a day). I might try just going pure regex.

@AdamCameron I was not aware of the existence of Code Review but thanks for telling me indirectly as well as catching that loop variable. As @DanBracuk noticed, the code isn't critical and it was more of a for-convenience/for-fun endeavor. The code is a far from perfect attempt that could use review, with the comments being a way for me to express that feeling.

Comment: @Alex - It is a fun exercise. Unfortunately it is more challenging than you might expect because, for the most part, CF only exposes the values as strings you must parse. (I am not good enough with regex's to know if that approach is feasible :) Might want to open a separate question about one of the specific expressions that does not work (with an example). As for overall reviewing, agreed [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a better place for it.

Comment: Most definitely I'm going to need help on the regex itself as my regex knowledge is falling particular short, so I'll probably post it here soon enough. If there is a way to move this question though to CodeReview I'll gladly exercise it.

Comment: I just flagged it, asking if a moderator could migrate it. We will see what happens.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18152435/get-contents-of-brackets-using-regex-in-a-list-of-values Because my mind is going Dave.