# Get contents of brackets using regex in a list of values

Tags: java, regex, coldfusion

I'm trying to look for a regex (Coldfusion or Java) that can get me the contents between the brackets for each (param \d+) without fail. I've tried dozens of different types of regexes and the closest one I got is this one:

```
\(param \d+\) = \[(type='[^']*', class='[^']*', value='(?:[^']|'')*', sqltype='[^']*')\]
```

Which would be perfect, if the string that I get back from CF escaped single quotes from the value parameter. But it doesn't so it fails miserably. Going the route of a negative lookahead like so:

```
\[(type='[^']*', class='[^']*', value='(?:(?!', sqltype).)*', sqltype='[^']*')\]
```

Is great, unless for some unnatured reason there's a piece of code that quite literally has `, sqltype` in the value. I find it hard to believe I can't simply tell regex to scoop out the contents of every open and closed bracket it finds but then again, I don't know enough regex to know its limits.

Here's an example string of what I'm trying to parse:

```
(param 1) = [type='IN', class='java.lang.Integer', value='47', sqltype='cf_sql_integer'] , (param 2) = [type='IN', class='java.lang.String', value='asf , O'Reilly, really?', sqltype='cf_sql_varchar'] , (param 3) = [type='IN', class='java.lang.String', value='Th[is]is Ev'ery'thing That , []can break it ', sqltype= ', sqltype='cf_sql_varchar']
```

For the curious this is a sub-question to [Copyable Coldfusion SQL Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133942/copyable-coldfusion-sql-exception/18133943).

#### EDIT

This is my attempt at implementing @Mena's answer in CF9.1. Sadly it doesn't finish processing the string. I had to replace the `\\` with `\` just to get it to run at first, but my implementation might still be at fault.

This is the string given (pipes are just to denote boundary):

```
| (param 1) = [type='IN', class='java.lang.Integer', value='47', sqltype='cf_sql_integer'] , (param 2) = [type='IN', class='java.lang.String', value='asf , O'Reilly], really?', sqltype='cf_sql_varchar'] , (param 3) = [type='IN', class='java.lang.String', value='Th[is]is Ev'ery'thing That , []can break it ', sqltype ', sqltype='cf_sql_varchar'] |
```

This is my implementation:

```
    <cfset var outerPat = createObject("java","java.util.regex.Pattern").compile(javaCast("string", "\((.+?)\)\s?\=\s?\[(.+?)\](\s?,|$)"))>
    <cfset var innerPat = createObject("java","java.util.regex.Pattern").compile(javaCast("string", "(.+?)\s?\=\s?'(.+?)'\s?,\s?"))>
    <cfset var outerMatcher = outerPat.matcher(javaCast("string", arguments.params))>

    <cfdump var="Start"><br />
    <cfloop condition="outerMatcher.find()">     
        <cfdump var="#outerMatcher.group(1)#"> (<cfdump var="#outerMatcher.group(2)#">)<br />
        <cfset var innerMatcher = innerPat.matcher(javaCast("string", outerMatcher.group(2)))>
        <cfloop condition="innerMatcher.find()">
            <cfoutput>|__</cfoutput><cfdump var="#innerMatcher.group(1)#"> --> <cfdump var="#innerMatcher.group(2)#"><br />
        </cfloop>
        <br />
    </cfloop>
    <cfabort>
```

And this is what printed:

```
Start 
param 1 ( type='IN', class='java.lang.Integer', value='47', sqltype='cf_sql_integer' )
|__ type --> IN 
|__ class --> java.lang.Integer 
|__ value --> 47 

param 2 ( type='IN', class='java.lang.String', value='asf , O'Reilly )
|__ type --> IN 
|__ class --> java.lang.String 

End
```

Comment: _"unless for some unnatured reason there's a piece of code that quite literally has `, sqltype` in the value."_ - so what do you think the query for _this very question_ would look like...?

Comment: btw, I'm pretty sure I've seen an alternative debug template out there that solves this issue, potentially by dealing with the debug data directly. Do you have particular CF versions / CFML engines you're looking for this to work with?

Comment: The exact CF is 9.1, and I very much enjoyed the debug template article (that was in fact an answer in the main question). The problem is that when an error occurs on production all I have to work with is the exception object that gets parsed on a page and then packaged and sent via email so it doesn't really help in this instance.

Comment: Hrm, ideally you'd still do the same thing to whatever generates the exception, but I don't think that's editable anywhere. :/ Is the string to parse definitely all on one line, or does it happen to contain newlines before each `(param x)` bit?

Comment: @PeterBoughton - No. Unfortunately ACF just concatenates everything as a single line, separated only by `(space),`.

Comment: Stupid thing. Since it at least uses the param numbers in the sql, it should be possible to scan backwards for the last `(param X)` and use that to check that the number of matched params is the same.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if that approach might be better. Really wish they should just make the params available as an array, and let developers do with them whatever they want. It should not be hard to add extra key to the cfcatch exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a Java regex pattern that works for your sample input.

```
(?x)

# lookbehind to check for start of string or previous param
# java lookbehinds must have max length, so limits sqltype
(?<=^|sqltype='cf_sql_[a-z]{1,16}']\ ,\ )

# capture the full string for replacing in the orig sql
# and just the position to verify against the match position
(\(param\ (\d+)\))

\ =\ \[

# type and class wont contain quotes
   type='([^']++)'
,\ class='([^']++)'

# match any non-quote, then lazily keep going
,\ value='([^']++.*?)'

# sqltype is always alphanumeric
,\ sqltype='cf_sql_[a-z]+'

\]

# lookahead to check for end of string or next param
(?=$|\ ,\ \(param\ \d+\)\ =\ \[)
```

*(The `(?x)` flag is for comment mode, which ignores unescaped whitespace and between a hash and end of line.)*

And here's that pattern implemented in CFML (tested on CF9,0,1,274733).  It uses [cfRegex](http://cfregex.net) (a library which makes it easier to work with Java regex in CFML) to get the results of that pattern, and then does a couple of checks to make sure the expected number of params are found.

```
<cfsavecontent variable="Input">
(param 1) = [type='IN', class='java.lang.Integer', value='47', sqltype='cf_sql_integer']
 , (param 2) = [type='IN', class='java.lang.String', value='asf , O'Reilly, really?', sqltype='cf_sql_varchar']
 , (param 3) = [type='IN', class='java.lang.String', value='Th[is]is Ev'ery'thing That , []can break it ', sqltype= ', sqltype='cf_sql_varchar']
</cfsavecontent>
<cfset Input = trim(Input).replaceall('\n','')>

<cfset cfcatch = 
    { params = input
    , sql = 'SELECT stuff FROM wherever WHERE (param 3) is last param'
    }/>

<cfsavecontent variable="ParamRx">(?x)

    # lookbehind to check for start or previous param
    # java lookbehinds must have max length, so limits sqltype
    (?<=^|sqltype='cf_sql_[a-z]{1,16}']\ ,\ )

    # capture the full string for replacing in the orig sql
    # and just the position to verify against the match position
    (\(param\ (\d+)\))

    \ =\ \[

    # type and class wont contain quotes
       type='([^']++)'
    ,\ class='([^']++)'

    # match any non-quote, then lazily keep going if needed
    ,\ value='([^']++.*?)'

    # sqltype is always alphanumeric
    ,\ sqltype='cf_sql_[a-z]+'

    \]

    # lookahead to check for end or next param
    (?=$|\ ,\ \(param\ \d+\)\ =\ \[)

</cfsavecontent>

<cfset FoundParams = new Regex(ParamRx).match
    ( text = cfcatch.params
    , returntype = 'full'
    )/>

<cfset LastParamPos = cfcatch.sql.lastIndexOf('(param ') + 7 />
<cfset LastParam = ListFirst( Mid(cfcatch.sql,LastParamPos,3) , ')' ) />

<cfif LastParam NEQ ArrayLen(FoundParams) >
    <cfset ProblemsDetected = true />
<cfelse>
    <cfset ProblemsDetected = false />

    <cfloop index="i" from=1 to=#ArrayLen(FoundParams)# >

        <cfif i NEQ FoundParams[i].Groups[2] >
            <cfset ProblemsDetected = true />
        </cfif>

    </cfloop>
</cfif>

<cfif ProblemsDetected>
    <big>Something went wrong!</big>
<cfelse>
    <big>All seems fine</big>
</cfif>

<cfdump var=#FoundParams# />
```

This will actually work if you embed an entire param inside the value of another param. It fails if you try two (or more), but at least least the checks should detect this failure.

Here's what the dump output should look like:

[image: dump output]

Hopefully everything here makes sense - let me know if any questions.

Comment: Peter - I am probably missing something silly, but when I run the above under 9,0,1,274733 the result is "Something went wrong!". Any other requirements besides installing cfRegex?

Comment: Nope - for this you can just drop  the CFC in the same directory as the script and it should be fine. I just copy-pasted the code here into a new file in a new directory, then dropped in Regex.cfc and it works fine.

Comment: The "Something went wrong" message should still be followed by the dump - can you see anything obviously broken there?

Comment: The dump just showed an empty array. But .. now that I have had sleep, I figured out it was just a stupid copy+paste problem ;-) Once I substituted `replace(Input, chr(13), "", "all")` for `trim(Input).replaceall('\n','')` it worked like a charm. Awesome job!

Comment: Was just able to implement this and test it and so far so good! Thanks! GG!

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use a dedicated parser for that, but here's an example on how to do it with two `Pattern`s and nested loops:

```
// the input String
String input = "(param 1) = " +
        "[type='IN', class='java.lang.Integer', value='47', sqltype='cf_sql_integer'] , " +
        "(param 2) = " +
        "[type='IN', class='java.lang.String', value='asf , O'Reilly, really?', " +
        "sqltype='cf_sql_varchar'] , " +
        "(param 3) = " +
        "[type='IN', class='java.lang.String', value='Th[is]is Ev'ery'thing That , "                "[]can break it ', sqltype= ', sqltype='cf_sql_varchar']";

// the Pattern defining the round-bracket expression and the following 
// square-bracket list. Both values within the brackets are grouped for back-reference
// note that what prevents the 3rd case from breaking is that the closing square bracket 
// is expected to be either followed by optional space + comma, or end of input
Pattern outer = Pattern.compile("\\((.+?)\\)\\s?\\=\\s?\\[(.+?)\\](\\s?,|$)");

// the Pattern defining the key-value pairs within the square-bracket groups
// note that both key and value are grouped for back-reference
Pattern inner = Pattern.compile("(.+?)\\s?\\=\\s?'(.+?)'\\s?,\\s?");
Matcher outerMatcher = outer.matcher(input);
// iterating over the outer Pattern (type x) = [myKey = myValue, ad lib.], or end of input
while (outerMatcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(outerMatcher.group(1));
    Matcher innerMatcher = inner.matcher(outerMatcher.group(2));
    // iterating over the inner Pattern myKey = myValue
    while (innerMatcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("\t" + innerMatcher.group(1) + " --> " + innerMatcher.group(2));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
param 1
    type --> IN
    class --> java.lang.Integer
    value --> 47
param 2
    type --> IN
    class --> java.lang.String
    value --> asf , O'Reilly, really?
param 3
    type --> IN
    class --> java.lang.String
    value --> Th[is]is Ev'ery'thing That , []can break it
```

Comment: I tried your answer but no dice. I edited in my results into the question.

Comment: @Alex my answer was for Java (your question stated "Coldfusion **or** Java" and I didn't take it further... - maybe I should have). If you try my answer as pure Java code, it will work. Within your XML though, I am not qualified enough to answer what's wrong :(

Comment: I appreciate the help either way. The reason I added the "or Java" is because I can use the underlying Java methods in CF (the Java regex is much more robust than what CF offers). I was just hoping I could easily interpret any Java code into a CF equivalent. Again though, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Alex you're welcome. Sorry I couldn't give you something to work with :(

Comment: At a quick glance, Alex's translation is an accurate one, so should work the same. However, I think this solution is too generic - even if it works it wont perform as well as it could. (I've got a pattern which I think will work - just sanity-checking it before I post.)